# Mendeley - can not search catalog anymore "client is not allowed"

Tags: mendeley

Since last week, the catalog search on Mendeley API is giving me the following result:

```
{
    "message": "Client ID <client_id> is not allowed",
    "status": 403
}
```

I am using standard code in Python that worked before:

```py
mendel = Mendeley(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
auth = mendel.start_client_credentials_flow()
session = auth.authenticate()

print(session.catalog.search('Nitrogen dynamics', view='all').list(50).items)
```

And I have the same result using curl:

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    -u client_id:client_secret \
    -d "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=all" \
    https://api.mendeley.com/oauth/token

curl -X GET "https://api.mendeley.com/search/catalog?access_token={access_token}"
```